# C++: Is there a point to add const to POD that are passed as arguments?

Tags: c++, constants

Imagine a function signature that accepts int or unsigned int or any POD.
Is there any benefits to const them if you are just reading from them>?

The only one I can think of, is so that you don't mess up and assign to it accidentally?

Comment: Why don't you provide an example in code?

Comment: Not unless you are passing it by reference.

Comment: What do you mean by POD? You do know that a `class` can also be POD, right?

Comment: Yep.  That would be why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am assuming that you are talking about the top-level qualifier as in `void f( const type x )`, rather than the const of the pointed/referred object. In that case, it is important to note that the language determines that the top level const-volatile qualifier in function arguments is removed from the signature of the function, that is, the following declare the same function:

```
void f( int );
void f( const int );
void f( volatile int );
void f( const volatile int );
```

From that point of view, in the *declaration* there is no point in adding cv-qualifiers. Now in the definition the cv-qualifiers are actually checked by the compiler, and in that case it will flag changes to the arguments as errors. I have seen some people suggesting you should and some suggesting you should not use `const` in the definitions to catch mistakes, but in most code I have seen, `const` was not used.

Answer (score 8):

> The only one I can think of, is so that you don't mess up and assign to it accidentally?

Yes, that's the point of `const`.  Because of that, it's easier to analyse and reason about the purpose and correctness of the function.

Still, it's generally considered bad practice to make by-value (i.e. non-pointer/non-reference) arguments in public APIs `const`: if you later want to modify them in the implementation you'll need to choose between:
- edit the public header to remove `const`, which can trigger recompilation of client code (as is common with file modification timestamp driven `make` rules),
  - if you don't remove the `const` from the implementation you may be forced to make an inefficient copy to yet another variable just to be able to modify the value....
- allow the declaration and definition to differ, which can confuse programmers flicking between the two (if they remember seeing it const somewhere but that isn't the implementation, they may make assumptions that prove to be wrong - the same danger doesn't exist for a non-`const` declaration that is actually `const` - at worst they check things unnecessarily carefully to find out the current state of the variable).

So, for functions internal to an implementation file, use `const` if you think it adds value (sometimes the verbosity is enough to make you not bother), but actively avoid it in public header files.

In Exceptional C++, Herb Sutter recommends:

> "Avoid const pass-by-value parameters in function declarations. Still make the parameter const in the same function's definition if it won't be modified."

Comment: Your explanation doesn't make sense to me. If you have a function declared `void f(const int);` in a header file you can change it to `void f(int b) { }` in the implementation file if you _really_ find you want to change the parameter without touching the header file.

Comment: Hi Charles: fair point - have updated my answer.  The function signatures are the same - they can link.  Just verbose and potentially dangerously misleading for the programmer having `const` in the declaration if it doesn't even apply to the implementation.

Comment: How could it be "dangerously misleading"? The caller doesn't care how it's implemented, he's just passing a value.

Comment: @Charles: a programmer studying the API may remember seeing the parameter as `const`, then find him/herself looking through the implementation with that belief in the back of his/her head - make some code changes based on the false premise that the value is necessarily still what the caller provided etc..

Comment: This is a case of "slow programmer" surely? If the parameter is being passed by value then regardless of whether the function was declared and/or defined with or without `const` in any combination then the function cannot change the value of any object that the caller passed in (provided the function does not have access to that object via an alternative alias). Nothing dangerous can arise from the a misconception of whether `const` was used or not in the definition. It's completely irrelevant. I agree with your conclusion but not your argument.

Comment: @Charles: "cannot change the value of any object that the caller passed in" - true, but that's doesn't comprehensively describe the ways errors may be introduced into the program... invalid reasoning about the behaviour within the function can itself compromise the program's correctness.

Answer (score 3):

const correctness should be used more of an contract and not as an tool for optimization when used in function arguments.
It makes usage more intuitive and prevents honest programmers from making errors, other than than modern day compilers are competent enough to apply any optimizations required.

Comment: But what about the dishonest programmers?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: they merit their fate.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Dishonest programmers(hackers or crackers) will break contracts and programs at will, you can't do much about them.

Comment: Honest programmers are OK. Dishonest ones can't be avoided. It's the clueless ones you worry about.

Answer (score 1):

Let's clarify one thing: pointers qualify as POD, and it's common practice to declare them `const`.

As a matter of convention integer and floating-point parameters are never declared const, even if your function has no intention of changing them within its body. Any changes are only within the context of the function itself and never propagate back to the caller, so from the perspective of the public interface of the function declaring them `const` is redundant.

Comment: Declaring the pointer itself as `const` is fairly unusual. Declaring it to point *to* a `const` object is quite common. The same is true in general: `const` modifying the argument itself is generally pointless; `const` modifying what it points at/refers to is common.

Answer (score -1):

No need to decorate an int or uint param with const.

In this way, value was passed: a copy of this int or uint is generated and passed into your function. Within the function, any change won`t affect this outside int or unit.

Use const with pointer param.